# Roblox HttpPost

Tags: php, lua, http-post, roblox

I cannot get the HttpService's PostAsync method to pass my data into the `$_POST` variable (php). According to the documentation, it should be passed as 'data' (`$_POST['data']`), but I'm getting nothing. `var_dump($_POST)` says that it's just an empty array.

Here's the bit of code in my lua script

```
    local json = HS:JSONEncode(chatLog)
    chatLog = {}
    print(json)
    print(HS:PostAsync(
        URL,
        json,
        Enum.HttpContentType.ApplicationJson
    ))
```

And here's the php on my website

```
echo 'Test';
var_dump($_POST);
echo $_POST['data'];
```

`print(json)` reveals that the data is exactly as it should be, but it's not showing up in the php.

Changing the Enum in the lua (or removing it entirely) doesn't change the behavior. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Can you var_dump your $_GET?

Comment: It's the same empty array.

Comment: appended ?key=value to the end of my url and the $_GET now contains key with value. So the GET isn't broken...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content type needed to be `Enum.HttpContentType.ApplicationUrlEncoded`. In addition, I appended "data=" to the front of my JSON string.

```
local json = HS:JSONEncode(chatLog)
chatLog = {}
json="data="..json
print(json)
print(HS:PostAsync(
    URL,
    json,
    Enum.HttpContentType.ApplicationUrlEncoded
))
```